# De-allocation of arrays in std::vector members

Tags: c++, std

This is a question about scope of arrays inside std::vector member structures.

Suppose I have next code:

```
struct memberStruct {
...
char array[5];
...
};

std::vector <memberStruct> _workVector;
```

The question: Which of vector clear methods (clear/erase/pop_back) ensure memberStruct.array de-allocation AKA going out of scope?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The member `array` is part of the enclosing structure `memberStruct`, there is no need to allocate or deallocate it. The `vector` will allocate/deallocate instances of `memberStruct` and that will take care of the members inside these instances as well.

Comment: OK. And will `push_back(localStaractVar)` method and `[] operator` call copy constructor?

Comment: @BaruchLi `push_back` will *use* the copy-ctor of `memberStruct`. Each type (`class` or `struct`) can have either a default-generated copy-ctor or a user-defined one. Maybe [this FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757) helps.

Answer (score 2):

`array` will be part of the `memberStruct`. This struct will be 5 bytes + other members + padding. So the answer to your question is: every method you mention will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Think of

```
...
char array[5];
...
```

as equivalent to

```
...
char array_0;
char array_1;
char array_2;
char array_3;
char array_4;
...
```

and things may become clear.

This is very different from

```
char *array = new char[5];
```

where the five bytes are stored outside your struct, and *do* need special handling.